# SharePoint User Profile error - 5000 entries for the below error in event viewer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, profile-sync

```
"The extensible extension returned an unsupported error.
```

The stack trace is:

""System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: More than one DN specified for the same profile.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileImportExportService.AddDNLookupTable(UserProfileApplicationProxy upaProxy, Guid partitionID, Int64 recordId, String objectType, String distinguishedName)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileImportExportService.<>c__DisplayClass26.b__24(Int32 idx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__10(Object param0)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileImportExportService.UpdateWithProfileChangeData(Int64 importExportId, ProfileChangeData[] profileChangeData)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebServiceDirectProxy.WebMethodInfo.Invoke(Object webServiceInstance, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebServiceDirectProxy.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ManagementAgent.ProfileImportExportDirect.UpdateWithProfileChangeData(Int64 importExportId, ProfileChangeData[] profileChangeData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ManagementAgent.ProfileImportExportExtension.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMAExtensibleCallExport.ExportEntry(ModificationType modificationType, String[] changedAttributes, CSEntry csentry)
Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.51"""

Comment: From your log: `More than one DN specified for the same profile.` Try look here: 1. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9ebba287-c94c-408a-afbb-3e6a280c17be/rebuilt-user-profile-service-maaextension-export-errors-in-fiim-sync?forum=sharepointadminprevious 2. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sajiths/2014/12/03/sp2013-adimport-more-than-one-dn-specified-for-the-same-profile/

Comment: the second link is broken